# How I can find all the elements in DOM having z-index value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a table in my code which contains lots of rows and every row contains some td's, I want to find all the td's having z-index value.

For Example -

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="z-index: 10">jhon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                doy
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="z-index: 20">jam</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Can anybody help me to find all the td's having z-index value without using any loop?**

Comment: Technically speaking, this should work: `$('td[style*="z-index"]')`. Basically you are using the native attribute selector.

Comment: @Terry though only for those elements which have their z-index set inline, correct?

Comment: @OliverRadini Yes. That’s is what OP is asking though, and it’s similar to your answer. If you want to get the computed style, using `element.style` will not work either.

Comment: @Terry Ah, I can't find that in the question; the example they give only specifies them that way but it seemed a little unreliable to presume that's the only way that z-index could be set for them?

Comment: Also, there is no reason why you want to avoid loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the `td`'s, then filter out those which don't have any z-index set. I'm fairly sure there's no way to do the initial select on a more specific level than this.

```js
const test = [
  ...document.getElementsByTagName("td")
].filter(x => x.style.zIndex !== "")

test.forEach(x => x.style.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16))

console.dir(test)
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="z-index: 10">jhon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                doy
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="z-index: 20">jam</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @oliver for the help but I already know this method but I want to find it without adding any loop either by jquery or JS.

Comment: @onkar.v I'm pretty sure that's impossible

Comment: yeh, I've tried lots of things for it but did not found any thing :(

Answer (score 0):

So this is give you the same result but with jquery and this is why i added a

`position:relative`

[For z-index to work correctly, every element that has a z-index property must also have any position set ( e.g.position:relative )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744801/z-index-not-working-inside-a-table)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").each(function() {

    // td Element
    const $this = $(this);

    // your logic condition 
    if ($this.css("z-index") !== "auto") {
      $this.css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style=" position: relative; z-index: 10">jhon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        doy
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style=" position: relative; z-index: 20">jam</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```