# how to remove the overlapping the following divs in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mern

[this is the picture which i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtgCr.png)] i am writing this code.
i already use z-index in both divs but it is not woring here. i think problem in my message code. can you identify it. i am weak in CSS.
Dropdown Menu

```
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  // box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 6px white;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #00000008;
  z-index: -1;
  max-height: 0;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-container:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown-container:focus .dropdownnew {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
Message code
.message-orange {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(100% - 400px);
    margin-left: calc(100% - 400px);
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744854/11667949 ?

Comment: That really depends on your DOM and your elements positioning. `z-index` does not respect *any* element on the page, only the ones within the same position context. The container of your dropdown menu needs to have a higher z-index than the container of the content below.  The z-index needs to be set within the same parent element.

Comment: It would really help to see the relevenat html as well for context. One thing to note with z-index is if B sits on top of A, a child element of A can never be on top of B regardless of the index.